# Yii2: how to remove required attribute in a view?

Tags: html, yii2, required

I have a text field that was defined as required in its model. But a view needs not be required. I try this way to remove the **required** attribute but it doesn't work:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'city')->textInput(['required' => false]) ?>
```

I need to change it in a **view** or in its **controller**. But not in its **model** (because others view needs the required attribute.).

I know how to do it using **jQuery** but I prefer with **PHP/Yii2**.

***Update (requiered by the nice help of @Muhammad Omer Aslam):***

- My model is called **Persons**.
- My view is called **_form**.
- My controller is called **PersonsControllers**. It has the update function:

actionUpdate($id):

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id); // How to add my new scenario here?

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_person]);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [scenarios](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models#scenarios) to make the field required or not for the specific view. You can assign the active fields that are required for the scenario, and those fields will be the subject to validation.

I assume the model is `Profile`. In below example `firstname`, `lastname` and `city` is required in the default scenario.

A model may be used in different scenarios, by default the scenario `default` is used. Let's say in your case we can declare a scenario `special` that will only require `firstname` and `lastname`. In your model, you will declare a constant for the scenario name, and then override the `scenarios()` method, `key=>value` pairs with the active field names being passed in form of an array to the `value` will be assigned.

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Profile extends ActiveRecord
{
    const SCENARIO_SPECIAL = 'special';

    public function scenarios()
    {
        $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
        $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_SPECIAL] = ['firstname', 'lastname'];
        return $scenarios;
    }
}
```

and then inside your `controller/action` for that view where you do not want the `city` field to be required, initialize the `Profile` model object as below

```
public function actionProfile(){
    $model = new \common\models\Profile(['scenario'=> \common\models\Profile::SCENARIO_SPECIAL]);
    return $this->render('profile',['model'=>$model]);
}
```

Now if you submit the form inside this view it will ask only for the `firstname` and `lastname` whereas in your previous forms/views if you try to submit the form it will ask you to provide the `city` when trying to submit, you don't have to change or add anything for the rest of the forms or the rules.

---

As you are trying to update the record and do not want the `city` to be required when updating the record, the only difference that could be is to assign the scenario like below as you are not creating a new object for the model.

```
$model->scenario=\common\models\Profile::SCENARIO_SPECIAL;
```

Comment: my function is not actionProfile() is actionUpdate($id). I tried this but didn't work: $model = $this->findModel($id, ['scenario' => Profile::SCENARIO_SPECIAL]);

Comment: you havent added anything other than the form field please add **complete** action code you are working on i assumed you were creating a new record but looks like you are trying to update the record and donot want the city to be required when updating ? as the `$this->findModel($id)` wasnt anywhere in your question @RobySottini

Comment: just update the scenario after you find the model like `$model->scenario='update'` and change the name in the `scenarios()` function from `special` to `update` if you donot want to be required on `update`, the name `update` is just a string or name that can be anything you just need to set the `scenario` to that name and set the fields that are required for it sam as i have provided in example @RobySottini

Answer (score 0):

In the model:

```
const SCENARIO_MYSPECIAL = 'myspecial';

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id_person', 'city'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_DEFAULT], 
        [['id_person'], 'required', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_MYSPECIAL],
    ];
}
```

In the controller:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->scenario = 'myspecial';

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_person]);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: I think you could have selected the answer below, as you didnt provided any action details, and the answer suggested below deals with the `new` object rather than selecting the existing `model`, thats the only difference, otherwise the concept is to assign the `scenario` name to be triggered at the required time, i have updated the answer below too, cheers.

Comment: and try assigning the value via the `const` that you declared in your model like `$model->scenario=Profile::SCENARIO_SPECIAL;` rather than providing string manually, it will be more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

go to the model and remove the attribute

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id_person', 'city'], 'required'], 
        [['id_person'], 'required'],
    ];
}
```

EX:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id_person'], 'required'], 
        [['id_person'], 'required'],
    ];
}
```